# Google Maps V3: Styled maps suddenly lost their styles?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I was working on my site last night and suddenly my styled map went back to the default style. Looking around it seems that the styles on [Google's own blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/add-touch-of-style-to-your-maps.html) aren't working.
Even the [Map style wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) is not working.

I thought this might just be me, but I have looked in both Firefox and Chrome and on two different computers. Strangely, it does seem that there are [some maps](http://martijnpannevis.nl/blog/2010/07/13/google-styled-maps-are-quite-powerful/) that are still styled.
Has there been a change in the syntax? None of my code has changed.

My site is [here](http://todoseventos.heroku.com/) if you want to look for yourself. Can someone confirm this for me? Can you see a problem with my js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a deprecated field. Change rules to stylers and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just had the same problem with my implementation, just stopped working in the last 12 hours or so. I am going to try and figure out whats gone wrong because as you said, some are still working.

skarE's post fixed it for me, nice one!

Comment: Thanks for posting that. It was about 12 hours ago for me too. Really sudden. It makes you feel a little crazy when stuff like that happens so it good to know when someone else is seeing it!